# error Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

i am getting the error of XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://abc' is therefore not allowed access..
i am very new in php and codeigniter and so i cannot really understand what is going on. i tried reading other materials here in stackoverflow but it just left me blank. I am sorry if this is a duplicate post to you but I really need help.

here is the ajax call for the view:

```
$("#btnLoginFB").click(function()
{       
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Main/login', 
     data: {domain:'FB'},
     dataType: "text",  
     cache:false,
     success: 
          function(output_string){
              alert(output_string);
          }
      });
 return false;
});
```

and here is the functions in the controller

```
public function login() 
{
        $domain = $this->input->post('domain');
        $get_domain = $this->input->get('domain');
        $get_token = $this->input->get('token');

        if ((!empty($get_domain)) && (!empty($get_token)))
        {   
            $this->getmasterid();       
        }
        else
        {
            $this->getticket($domain);
        }
}

public function getsomething($domain)
{

    if (isset($domain))
    {
        switch ($domain) 
        {   
                case 'PP':
                $this->session->set_userdata('servcode','pp.login');
                $this->session->set_userdata('servsiggy','adgjanlnadgakjdbakg');
                $this->session->set_userdata('domain','pp');
                break;
            case 'FB':
                $this->session->set_userdata('servcode','fb.login');
                $this->session->set_userdata('servsiggy','213453a4sfasga5g4ad');
                $this->session->set_userdata('domain','fb');
                break;
            default:
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                header("Location: index.php");
                break;
        }

        $this->session->set_userdata('clientpaddr', $this->input->server('REMOTE_ADDR'));
        $this->session->set_userdata('partcode', 'abc');
        $this->session->set_userdata('command', 'initialize-something');
        $this->session->set_userdata('layout', 'deflt');
        $this->session->set_userdata('title', 'pp login');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captcha', 'false');
        $this->session->set_userdata('keys', 'false');
        $this->session->set_userdata('returnurl', 'https://mywebsite.game.com/login.php');
        $this->session->set_userdata('cancelurl', 'https://mywebsite.game.com/cancel.php');
        $this->session->set_userdata('sendurl', 'http://192.168.0.1/authenticate/green/api.ashx');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->session->userdata('sendurl'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $data = array(
       'part_code' => $this->session->userdata('partcode'),
       'serv_code' => $this->session->userdata('servcode'),
       'serv_siggy' => $this->session->userdata('servsiggy'),
       'command' => $this->session->userdata('command'),
       'ip' => $this->session->userdata('clientpaddr'),
       'domain' => $this->session->userdata('domain'),
       'layout' => $this->session->userdata('layout'),
       'required_captcha' => $this->session->userdata('captcha'),
       'required_keys' => $this->session->userdata('keys'),
       'return_url' => $this->session->userdata('returnurl'),
       'cancel_url' => $this->session->userdata('cancelurl')
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $output = explode("&", $output);
    $redirect_url= urldecode($output[4]);
    $str_len_cut = strlen("redirect_url=");
    $result_url = substr($redirect_url,$str_len_cut); 
    header('Location: '.$result_url); 
}
```

Comment: btw, the link in the sendurl is a server from another place, so I have no access with their web service APIs

Comment: Just to be clear, you are calling your own php page with the XHR ?

Comment: no.. im calling a login page from another webserver

Comment: Hmm, what does `base_url()` return ?

Comment: its just a path to connect the button to my controller.. example of that is localhost/apps/webPage/Main/login ..

Comment: oh yeah, thank you so much for taking your time to answer my inquiries i'm very bothered earlier that no one would read my post.

Comment: Which means the XHR is indeed trying to call your own php script. It's your php that tries to call an outside url after that.

Comment: im sorry i dont know what to do now.. i really am a newbie in php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the controller, set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** at the top of your php script to the expected value of the origin header, the domain your ajax calls from:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: abc');
```

Or if you never use credentials and don't care where the request comes from, just use a wildcard:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

### update 2015-07-13 12:34 +0000

> **Disclaimer**
>   I think I failed to properly consider that this was done under codeigniter and it now seems to me this answer is pretty poor.

Comment: wait.. im using codeigniter so im a little confused.. currently the AJAX call is in the view, then the functions are in a CI_Controller.. where do i put the Access-Control-Allow-Origin? at the view or controller?

Comment: In the controller, as it is the requested resource and needs to tell the view (really the browser) it is authorised to be fetched.

Comment: so i tried to put the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the index of my controller.. and it still says it cannot load it, i'm really sorry maybe if you are the one doing the codes here it would be really easy for you..

Comment: You've put `header(...)` at the top of main/login and it gives the same error ?

Comment: yes I have tried putting the header(...) at the login function and I also tried in the index and it still displays the error

Comment: Spamming comments might be a bit inefficient, let's try chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82894/q31332202

Comment: Hmm your rep might be to low for chat actually.

Comment: You've put `header(...)` at the very top of main/login ? Really as the first line right after `<?php` ?

Comment: yes, my rep is still too low. do you have a skype or something we could try to talk there? after you said after the line in php I tried putting it there and still the error persists.

Comment: I used a different approach to the problem so its fine now.. i think.. thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same problem. please keep in mind you have to put

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in other side.

For example, you are requesting ajax from

```
http://example.net
```

to `http://example2.net/login`
so you have to put above code at `http://example2.net/login` files.

Comment: But where it has to put.?

Comment: for all all - you can put it in index.php outside in root folder 
otherwise in constructor of particular controller if you want to allow for all functions.
for specific function you can put in starting of function.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter the way to do this is using the [output class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html). So you would put this in your controller wherever you need this.

```
$this->output
    ->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: some-origin')
    ->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS')
```

As a side note: it is generally bad practise to set your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` to `*` unless you really want to allow request from any domain. Otherwise it would be more secure to only allow requests from the domain(s) you are running your app on. More on this matter [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).