# How to solve Access-control-Allow_origin in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cors

I have just converted an HTML template to php. I have put the folders like css,js,and images at the root directory of codeigniter project. Using base_url function I have successfully fetched images and styles yet some of the icons are still missing and I am getting this error in console

```
Access to font at 'http://[::1]/diz/fonts/themify.woff?-fvbane' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have also put this line in my controller that loads the view of index page

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I expected it to solve the problem but it is not doing anything. I have also tried answers given by others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332202/error-access-control-allow-origin-header-on-codeigniter/31334148), but it did not help.

Thanks in advance

The response header in network is :

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 10:32:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.6
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 09:38:36 GMT
ETag: "db2c-583e27406bf00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 56108
Content-Type: font/woff

Comment: This is a problem you would not even have, if it was using the same host name in both places … I’d check the configuration to figure out why the font files are referred to using `http://[::1]/`, and not `http://localhost/`

Comment: Yes I am also confused why is this happening, I am not able to figure it out I just started codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");
```

If it not works u can try to configure your local server 
Apache:

```
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Allow from all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

and Nginx:

```
if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Comment: Can you send a response header?

Comment: I have edited the question see if I have added the content that you want or is it different